# How to update python dictionary based on time?

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

So the problem I am having in python is that every time I make a connection to my jira account, I can't seem to keep my previous python dictionary values.

The logic seems to fail in the for loop and when I assign empty dictionaries. Other than that, I did try to work around this issue by using a couple conditions, but those methods did not work out.

Here is what I mean.

**Current Code**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from jira.client import JIRA
from datetime import datetime
jira_token = os.getenv(<jira_personal_tokne>)
jira_link = os.getenv(<jira_url>)
jira_server = {"server": jira_link}
auth_jira = JIRA(options=jira_server, token_auth=jira_token)

proj = auth_jira.search_issues("project=<my_project> and 'epic link'='<epic_link_of_interest>'")

plmpgm_dict= {}
for i in proj:
   formatted_date = datetime.strptime(i.fields.updated, '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
   inner_dict = {}
   inner_dict["summary"]=i.fields.summary
   inner_dict["description"] = i.fields.description
   inner_dict["last_retrieved"] = formatted_date
   plmpgm_dict[i.key] inner_dict
   if i.key == "<jira issue>":
      print(plmpgm_dict)
```

**Output I get**:

```
{'<jira issue>':{
    'summary':'summary_values',
    'description: 'description values',
    'last_retrieved':'2022-03-11T19:44:15'
    }
}
```

**Output I want/expected**:

```
{'<jira issue>':{
    'summary':'summary_values',
    'description: 'description values',
    'last_retrieved':'2022-03-11T18:44:15'
    },{
    'summary':'old summary_values',
    'description: ' old description values',
    'last_retrieved':'2022-03-11T18:50:15'
    }
}
```

Now, I am wondering if there is a way to possibly store my previous python dictionary key-value pairs instead of being replaced with the new dictionary key-value pairs when I make a connection to jira using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your problem is about neither Jira nor Python.

When you run a program, all variables start from zero. It is programming logic. You need to save previous values, so you just need to save the data at some destination (File system, database, etc.)

**The Idea**

So, we need to save the data. It is a Python `dict` so we can save it as a `JSON` string. For now, let's say we're saving it inside a JSON file in system. And when you run the program, you should read this JSON file into `plmpgm_dict` variable.

You can use the following code for that operation:

```
import json

def dict_to_json_file(some_dict, file_name):
    fp = open(file_name, 'w+)
    fp.write(json.dumps(some_dict))
    fp.close()

def json_file_to_dict(file_name):
    fp = open(file_name, 'r+)
    some_dict = json.loads(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    return some_dict
```

**Algorithm**

Before the `for` loop, you need to read from the file (if exists) into `plmpgm_dict` with something like `plmpgm_dict = json_file_to_dict('dump.json')`.

After the `for` loop, at the end of your code, you need to dump the dict to the JSON file with something like `dict_to_json_file(plmpgm_dict, 'dump.json')`

Comment: Thanks @stuck, I knew it was a programming logic. I just did not know the idea. All I just need to do is fix some other issue.